# Are there any test data repositories regarding diacritics in text strings?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-data, data-quality, data-validation

I am about to test a software's handling of diacritics.

*a sign, such as an accent or cedilla, which when written above or below a letter indicates a difference in pronunciation from the same letter when unmarked or differently marked.*

Wikipedia's [diacritics article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) shows many examples. But I could not find a compilation of such characters for designated use in testing software anywhere online.

Do you know of any test data repositories? Regarding strings in general or diacritics in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of data for testing diacritics can be found at http://www.madore.org/~david/misc/unitest/#accents

Comment: Just what I was looking for, and many more useful test data, like Arabic, Greek and Chinese texts.

Answer (score 2):

The [Big List of Naughty Strings](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings/blob/master/blns.txt) is another good one - it's not just diacritics, but a whole lot of different unicode strings and a bunch of other strings that are known to cause problems in different applications.

(I am not affiliated - I just use it a lot)